# How to use UPDATE and IN in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

I have the tables like this(interconnected by Foreign Keys):

STUDENT:
    **SNUM**, SNAME, FEES

FACULTY:
    **FID**, FNAME

COURSE:
    **CNAME**, TIME, FID

ENROLLED:
    **SNUM,CNAME**

> Requirement:
>   Update FEES of students by 15%, for whom Prof. Kavya is teaching.

I tried the following query, which is not working

```
UPDATE STUDENT SET FEES=FEES*1.15 WHERE SNUM IN
(
SELECT DISTINCT S.SNUM 
FROM STUDENT S, COURSE C, ENROLLED E, FACULTY F 
WHERE S.SNUM = E.SNUM AND E.CNAME = C.CNAME 
AND C.FID = F.FID 
AND F.FNAME = 'KAVYA'
);
```

> Error: You can't specify target table STUDENT for update in FROM clause.

Kindly Help me to solve this problem

Comment: Can you try join ? UPDATE STUDENT S
JOIN ENROLLED E ON S.SNUM = E.SNUM
JOIN COURSE C ON E.CNAME = C.CNAME 
JOIN FACULTY F ON C.FID = F.FID 
SET FEES=FEES*1.15
WHERE F.FNAME = 'KAVYA';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a sub query which has been documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html). You can change the query into join instead of sub query as follows,

```
UPDATE STUDENT S
JOIN ENROLLED E ON S.SNUM = E.SNUM
JOIN COURSE C ON E.CNAME = C.CNAME 
JOIN FACULTY F ON C.FID = F.FID 
SET FEES=FEES*1.15
WHERE F.FNAME = 'KAVYA';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in `MySQL`, you can't update the same table which you have used in the `SELECT` query. You can change it by joining them instead:

```
UPDATE  STUDENT a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT S.SNUM 
            FROM    STUDENT S, COURSE C, ENROLLED E, FACULTY F 
            WHERE   S.SNUM = E.SNUM AND E.CNAME = C.CNAME 
                    AND C.FID = F.FID 
                    AND F.FNAME = 'KAVYA'
        ) b ON a.SNUM = b.SNUM
SET a.FEES = a.FEES * 1.15
```